# Convert to lowercase in Vim Visual mode until specific delimiter

Tags: vim, yaml

Basically i have a yml file and i want to convert the keys to lowercase.

example below.

```
KEY: value
ANOTHER_KEY: another_value
```

I tried the `vwu` and it works as expected but i want to apply in the whole file.

I also used the `.` (dot) to apply the above command using number & j multiple times.

Comment: are you okay with using regular expressions or macros?

Comment: Sure am i!

the dot did the job but i was looking a more intuitive way to do this in all the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
:%norm! guiw

 %  ................. the whole file
 norm! .............. in normal mode please
 gu ................. make {motion} text lowercase 
 iw ................. inner word
```

It also could be:

```
:%norm! gut:

t: .............. until :
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one approach is to use the `sub-replace-expression` functionality.  The following command:

```
:%s/\(\s*\)\(\w*\)\(.*\)/\= submatch(1) . tolower(submatch(2)) . submatch(3)/
```

Will, for each line, match `whitespace` `word` `whatever`, and replace it with the same thing but `word` being lowercase.  I'm assuming that you are familiar with the restrictions and usage of regular expressions so I won't go into all the details of why I did the expression that way, how to modify it, or restrictions with using them against a context-free language (I think?) like `yaml` here, but the `\=` token in the `:s` command can be pretty nifty.